# jQuery code not working as I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry about the title I just don't know what to set it as. If you can think of a title for this question please tell me or edit, thanks. Now to the question. I have written some jQuery code which displays different boxes depending on which link is clicked. And when you click the link again all the boxes reappear which is exactly what I want. My problem is that when I click link1 then link2 and then go back to link1 all the images reappear. I don't want this to happen. I only want the boxes for link1 to appear. All the boxes should only show at the start and when you click a link twice.

```js
$(".links").click(function(){
  var current_link = $(this);
  var images = $(".images")
  
  $(images).removeClass('hide');
  $(images).removeClass('show');
  
  var current = $(this).data("cat");
  $(images).addClass('hide');
  $('.'+current).addClass('show');
  
   $(current_link).click(function(){
      $(images).toggleClass('hide');
   });
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none; 
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.change{
  background-color: red;
}

.print{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.portfolio{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.web{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}

.show{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="hi" class="links" data-cat="print" href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="portfolio" href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="web" href="#">link3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="print images">
  
</div>

<div class="portfolio images">
  
</div>

<div class="web images">
  
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a condition on the links by adding a class **.active** and check if the link has that class, and use just the class **.hide** for the **.images**, no need to use class **.show**

**See code snippet**:

```js
$(".links").click(function() {

  var current_link = $(this);
  var images = $(".images");
  var links = $(".links");
  var current = $(this).data("cat");

  if (current_link.hasClass('active')) {
  
    links.removeClass('active');
    images.removeClass('hide');

  } else {
  
    links.removeClass('active');
    current_link.addClass('active');
    images.addClass('hide');
    $('.' + current).removeClass('hide');
  }

});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li,
.images {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.change {
  background-color: red;
}

.images {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.print {
  background-color: blue;
}

.portfolio {
  background-color: red;
}

.web {
  background-color: orange;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="hi" class="links" data-cat="print" href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="portfolio" href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="web" href="#">link3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="print images"></div>

<div class="portfolio images"></div>

<div class="web images"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain the current link in global variable or like I have done it inside the window object, Try this:

```js
$(".links").click(function(){
  var current_link = $(this);
  var images = $(".images")
  var current = $(this).data("cat");
  
  if(current == window.currentImage){
      $(images).removeClass('hide');
    $(images).removeClass('show');
    window.currentImage = null;
    return; // don't do anything id current link is clicked
  }
  
  $(images).addClass('hide');
  $('.'+current).removeClass('hide');
  $('.'+current).addClass('show');
  window.currentImage = current;
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none; 
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.change{
  background-color: red;
}

.print{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.portfolio{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.web{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
}

.show{
  display: inline-block;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="hi" class="links" data-cat="print" href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="portfolio" href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="web" href="#">link3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="print images">
  
</div>

<div class="portfolio images">
  
</div>

<div class="web images">
  
</div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be a cleaner solution for you. i am also using a condition :)

```js
var current = null;
var images = $('.images');

$(".links").click(function(){
  if(current === $(this).data("cat")){
    images.removeClass('hide');
    current = null;
  } else {
    current = $(this).data("cat");
    $(images).addClass('hide');
    $('.'+current).removeClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none; 
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.change{
  background-color: red;
}

.print{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.portfolio{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.web{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}

.show{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="hi" class="links" data-cat="print" href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="portfolio" href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="web" href="#">link3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="print images">

</div>

<div class="portfolio images">

</div>

<div class="web images">

</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```